# MVC Passing Key value to another table

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, insert

So i have 3 table: Series {SeriesID, etc.}, Seasons {SeriesID, EpisodeID, etc.}, Episodes {EpisdoeID, etc.}.

My goal is to add an episode to a Series, that means i only want to insert data to the seasons, and episode table.I figured that if i pass the seriesID to the season table itt will work fine but it gives me an error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.season_dbo.SeriesID". The conflict occurred in database "FilmDot", table "dbo.Series", column 'SeriesID'.

I created a viewmodel for this:

```
public class AddEpisodeModel
{
    public Guid SeriesID { get; set; }

    //season
    public int SeasonNumber { get; set; }

    //episode
    public int EpisodeNumber { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string YTlink { get; set; }
    public DateTime RelaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller:

```
public ActionResult AddEpisode(Guid id)
    {
        AddEpisodeModel model = new AddEpisodeModel();

        ViewBag.id = id;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEpisode(AddEpisodeModel model)
    {

        var season = new season
        {
            SeasonNumber = model.SeasonNumber
        };

        var episode = new episode
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            Description = model.Description,
            EpisodeNumber = model.EpisodeNumber,
            YTlink = model.YTlink,
            RelaseDate = model.RelaseDate
        };

        using (var context = new fContext())
        {
            context.Episode.Add(episode);
            season.EpisodeID = episode.EpisodeID;
            season.SeriesID = model.SeriesID;
            context.Season.Add(season);

            context.SaveChanges();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("SeasonList", new RouteValueDictionary(
                                new { controller = "Content", action = "SeasonList", id = model.SeriesID }));
    }
```

Comment: The problem was taht I wanted to set everything in the view, but u shouldnt pass the id in a viewbag because u just cant do anything with it, except displaying it.
So instead of ViewBag.id = id, u should update the model,seriesID = id instead, before u send it to the view. haha...